# Javascript: explicitly closing tags like <a/> with DOM manipulation

Tags: javascript, android, html, range, getclientrect

My Android app makes use of a WebView control where an HTML page is loaded. I am experiencing wrong behaviour of certain functions like range.getClientRects() when an user selects a range surrounding an empty anchor element like:

```
<a id='id' class='class'  />
```

and I suspect it can happen with other tags too.

I was said some browsers computes the a element to reach to the end of parent element, like a p for example, when range.getClientRects() is called. It's a wrong behaviour  in my app so I would like to avoid it by closing empty tags (anchors and also other types) if that doesn't break the rendered layout (it should remain exactly the same) with Javascript DOM manipulation after HTML is loaded.

```
<a id='id' class='class' ></a>
```

Is it possible?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to do this at the DOM level. Once you've got a DOM, the HTML (erroneous or not) has already been parsed, and it's no longer relevant. Self-closing tags are allowed in HTML5 documents, but it has no meaning - in other words, they're not really self-closing. A tag like `<a ... />` is exactly like the same tag without the `/`.

Comment: Of course XHTML is a different story.

Comment: @Pointy Please, tell me about XHTML, because I deal with it in fact (ePub files).

Comment: Well if you've *really* got an XHTML document, and the browser is correctly interpreting it as XHTML, then self-closing tags work. It has to be served with the proper MIME type (`application/xhtml+xml` I think) or else the browser will treat it as HTML.